# Problems after upgrading postgres and php

Tags: php, postgresql, apache, ubuntu

I'm on an ubuntu 16.04 server.

I upgraded postgresql from version 9.5 to 12.3.
I upgraded php from v 7.0 to 7.3.
I upgraded libpq-dev to 12.3-1.pgdg16.04+1

phpinfo() shows `php version 7.3` but it shows version `PostgreSQL 9.5.21` for pdo_pgsql and pgsql

apache logs show:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_pgsql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pgsql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

So what have I done wrong here and how do I get php / pdo using the correct versiion of pgsql / libpq?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`apt remove *-pgsql`

`apt install php7.3-pgsql`
then restart your apache